# What does "a sort of Hercules in strength and weakness" mean?

Tags: symbols, allusion

It says in Great Expectations, "Joe was a fair man, with curls of flaxen hair on each side of his smooth face, and with eyes of such a very undecided blue that they seemed to have somehow got mixed with their own whites. He was a mild, good-natured, sweet-tempered, easy-going, foolish, dear fellow - **a sort of Hercules in strength, and also in weakness.**" What does this mean/imply?

Link to the pdf of the whole book here: https://planetpdf.com/planetpdf/pdfs/free_ebooks/Great_Expectations_T.pdf

Comment: Do you know who Hercules was?

Comment: The main weakness of Hercules/Heracles was that he flew into rages and killed people (particularly out of jealousy). This really doesn't apply at all to Joe in Great Expectation.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, but I am having trouble matching Hercules to Joe

Comment: Stuart F seems to be picking up what you're putting down! Stuart, care to add a more detailed response? Perhaps Yosef is right to be struggling with understanding this? In any case I think it would be good to get the perspective of somebody else familiar with the book (which I most definitely am not!).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [literature.se]

Answer (score 2):

The [myth of Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules#Mythology) is defined by the fact that he, son of Zeus, is **NOT** a God, like the others on Mt. Olympus, but only a demi-god -- being the product of Zeus, a God, and Alcmene, a mortal. In this way, much of the tale is about Hercules, feeling unwanted in the realms of both Gods and men, finding a way to cope with his own mortality and define himself as his own person, not a God but a hero nevertheless.

I think just from the basic description of him being a demi-god, that pretty much explains it, no? He has God-like powers (in some contexts), yet in many others he is merely human. Lots of strengths, lots of weaknesses.

Comment: You did a great job explaining the weaknesses, but how would the strengths of Hercules apply to Joe? Otherwise, this is a great answer. +1

Comment: I'm sorry; I figured the implied focus of the question was wherein the _weaknesses_ played in, considering that if there's one thing anybody remotely familiar with Hercules is aware of, it's his many strengths.


Further, I thought you were asking about what *could* be meant by that particular turn of phrase; I see now that you were actually more interested in a detailed analysis of how the quote applies and makes sense in the context of the book. If that's the case, I overestimated my ability or willingness to fully answer the question, and I'm sorry for that! Good luck w/ a better answer!